# Изменение изображений в датасете mnist

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Задача:
Создайте автокодировщик, удаляющий черные квадраты в cлучайных областях изображений.
Алгоритм действий:

Возьмите базу картинок Mnist.
На картинках в случайных местах сделайте чёрные квадраты размера 8 на 8.
Создайте и обучите автокодировщик восстанавливать оригинальные изображения из "зашумленных" квадратом изображений.

Как можно наложить изображение квадрата на все изображения в датасете mnist?

Пытался напрямую наложить картинку, но не получается.

Работая в массиве, такой формат работает -

```
data = X_train[100]
for array in data:
  for a in array:
    data[15][15] = 100
    data[16][15] = 100
    data[17][15] = 100
    data[18][15] = 100
    data[19][15] = 100
    data[20][15] = 100
    data[21][15] = 100
    data[22][15] = 100
```

Но придется вводить 64 строки.

Почему не работает такой код?

```
data = X_train[100]
k = 15
n = 15
for array in data:
  for a in array:
     for number in range(8):
       data[k][15] = 100
       k = k + 1
     for number in range(8):
       data[15][n] = 100
       n = n + 1
```

Ошибка выход за границы массива

```
<ipython-input-170-064881553b92> in <module>()
      5   for a in array:
      6      for number in range(8):
----> 7        data[k][15] = 100
      8        k = k + 1
      9      for number in range(8):

IndexError: index 28 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 28
```

Comment: Перебрать в цикле все изображения. Заполнить нулями случайные области 8х8 на каждом из них. А вообще я надеюсь только рамку нужно чёрным заполнять? Там вроде 20х20 изображения, если сделать сплошные чёрные квадраты 8х8 потом вряд-ли что-то можно будет восстановить, мне кажется. А вообще интересная задачка.

Comment: А можно в коде пример? А то я только недавно изучаю питон и машинное обучение

Comment: @CrazyElf размер изображений в mnist 28x28

Comment: "Недавно изучаю" - это не аргумент, чтобы вообще не пытаться ничего делать самому. Обычно изображения это просто numpy array соответствующего размера, нужно просто в него нули записать. Для начала можно обычными циклами по x и y обойтись. Но вы хоть что-то почитайте, подумайте. Что толку, если весь код кто-то за вас напишет. Там ничего сложного вообще, только читать и думать.

Comment: я пытался, у меня получается нанести вертикальную полосу на всю высоту изображения, но именно квадрат - не получается

Comment: А вот и добавьте ваш код в вопрос, чтобы было видно, что вы пытались решить эту задачу.

Comment: добавил свой код

Answer (score 2):

Ладно, вот вам пример для одного случайного изображения. Там нет ничего сложного, каждое изображение - это квадратный массив `numpy` размером 28x28 и со значениями от 0 до 255. Его можно индексировать привычным образом `[x][y]` (ну или `[y][x]`, в вашем случае это совершенно не важно). Просто перебираете точки с нужными вам координатами и присваиваете нужные вам значения:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt      # MATLAB like plotting routines
import random                        # for generating random numbers
from keras.datasets import mnist     # MNIST dataset is included in Keras

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

num = random.randint(0, len(X_train))
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(X_train[num], cmap='gray', interpolation='none');
x_size, y_size = 8, 8
x_rnd, y_rnd = random.randint(0, 28-x_size), random.randint(0, 28-y_size)
for x in range(x_rnd, x_rnd + x_size):
    for y in range(y_rnd, y_rnd + y_size):
        X_train[num][x][y] = 128 # вариант [x, y] = 128 тоже работает
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(X_train[num], cmap='gray', interpolation='none');
```

Пример работы этого кода. Я заполняю точки серым цветом, так заметнее изменения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Советую вам изучить Jupyter Notebook с [примером](https://colab.research.google.com/github/AviatorMoser/keras-mnist-tutorial/blob/master/MNIST%20in%20Keras.ipynb#scrollTo=mDM_DxvcJTQg) работы с `MNIST` через `Keras`, из него можно лучше понять формат данных, как их отображать и т.д. Код в этом ответе я сделал из этого ноутбука.

**Примечание:** Можно вообще без цикла сразу область заполнить, так будет быстрее, спасибо Danis за замечание:

```
X_train[num][x_rnd:x_rnd+x_size, y_rnd:y_rnd+y_size] = 128
```

Comment: если это массив numpy, то изображение можно заполнить без цикла `X_train[num][x_rnd:x_rnd+x_size, y_rnd:y_rnd+y_sizd] = 128`

Comment: @Danis Да, вы правы. Но поскольку человек начинающий и дело не в скорости, а вообще в том, чтобы хоть что-то сделать для начала, я показал как это сделать банальным образом. Так то да, так быстрее конечно будет, если сразу весь срез заполнить.

Comment: @MaxU Ну забыл я что-то, что так тоже можно, забыл ))